# GStreamer on Android

Tags: android, c, ffmpeg, android-ndk, gstreamer

Can anyone give me any tips on getting GStreamer to work on Android. I have never used it before and I would like to use it with FFmpeg (I already have FFmpeg compiled and works fine on Android). I would just like to use GStreamer to help with some of the processing as learning the FFmpeg API is somewhat of a nightmare haha. Thanks in advance for any help at all!

Comment: Glib have to be ported to Android see http://groups.google.com/group/android-platform/browse_thread/thread/e3ba69545e1d31ac/439a80ecee837714

Comment: Thank you for the link, that was useful information.

Comment: There is also another link where i will track it when ever i get those all done. e.g: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5585538/285594

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/attic/gst-android/  It could be very useful.

Cheers
Kapil

Answer (score 4):

Try this link as well : 
http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/wiki/GstreamerAndroid_InstallInstructions

and also subscribe to the gstreamer android mailing list : 
http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/gstreamer-android

idealy you must build the gstreamer first for android and then port it and run a basic command on the adb shell for the sanity check.

Once this is done you can do the same for ffmpeg (which you have already done)
Download the ndk from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html) 
and then Try taking out the sample code from the ndk and add your c files in any of the simple jni programme .In c files you can programme the gstreamer and ffmpeg api calls.

You need to understand the ndk build [documentation](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html) as well.