# Gstreamer on iphone, blackberry, android, nokia? How would it perform?

Tags: iphone, c, blackberry, d, gstreamer

Gstreamer on IPhone, Android, Blackberry, Nokia. How can we make it using C or D or Vala languages? Or should we just use Java or Lua?

1) Glib porting to IPhone, Android, Blackberry, Nokia is available?

- For Android, there is a tips http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/wiki/GstreamerAndroid_InstallInstructions
- For IPhone, no idea
- For Nokia, no idea
- For Blackberry, no idea

Wish someone put some answers and feedback on this topic.

Comment: IIRC there are some fairly draconian restrictions on what programming languages can be used for iPhone apps.

Comment: This question is hopelessly broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about mobile development, but your best bet would be to look into [GtkD](http://www.dsource.org/projects/gtkd).  This project provides bindings to GTK and GObject.  AFAIK no D bindings to GStreamer exist yet, but [calling C code from D isn't difficult](http://digitalmars.com/d/2.0/interfaceToC.html).  Furthermore, to compile for ARM architectures, you'll probably want to look at [GDC](https://bitbucket.org/goshawk/gdc/wiki/Home) since the reference DMD implementation only targets x86/x64.

Comment: GtkD has GStreamer bindings: http://dsource.org/projects/gtkd/browser/trunk/srcgstreamer