# Android record audio with custom encoder

Tags: android, audio, encode, audio-recording, opus

Android have native audio [encoders](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.html) and audio [decoders](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html), and you can [record](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) and [play](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) with this native formats without problems, but you also can implements [your own](http://source.android.com/devices/media.html) audio codecs. I do not understood very well how to do it, anyone know an implementation of custom encode codecs in android platform? I'm trying do it with [opus](http://www.opus-codec.org/) format for be more specific, but any other codec format implementation can give-me an idea of how I can do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FFMPEG to endode/decode a lot of audio codecs.
see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4820282/763394
also you can have a look to gstreamer framework: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5780113/763394